# Specify XBAP at runtime, in my .NET WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, xbap

Can I host an XBAP in my WPF application dynamically?

Can I download an XBAP, set it to be hosted in my WPF application, and interact with it programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume "yes", since you can always place a [`WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in your application and then call [`Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491252.aspx) with the url to the XBAP application that you wish to launch.

As a matter of fact, this is [recomended in the documentation from Microsoft for the `IWpfHostSupport` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970784.aspx)

Specifically, in the "remarks" section (emphasis mine):

Win32 applications such as Web browsers can host WPF content, including XAML browser applications (XBAPs) and loose XAML.  **To host WPF content, Win32 applications create an instance of the WebBrowser control.**

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that is the obvious way of doing it. It would be nice to not have to use a browser.

Can I interact with the XBAP? (set and read properties)?